# Convert a list of long to a iterable of integers using Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

How could I convert a list of long to a list of integers. I wrote :

```
longList.stream().map(Long::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList())
//longList is a list of long.
```

I have an error :

```
Incompatible types. Required iterable<integer> but collect was inferred to R.
```

May anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Why would you expect `.map(Long::valueOf)` to convert long to integer?

Comment: Note: `.map` returns an Object, so when you call `Long.ValueOf` it will auto-box it back into a long, creating a new object (unless cached)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll need [`Long::intValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#intValue--) rather than [`Long::valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf-long-) as this function returns a `Long` type not `int`.

```
Iterable<Integer> result = longList.stream()
                                   .map(Long::intValue)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or if you want the receiver type as `List<Integer>`:

```
List<Integer> result = longList.stream()
                               .map(Long::intValue)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not concerned about overflow or underflows you can use `Long::intValue` however if you want to throw an exception if this occurs you can do

```
Iterable<Integer> result = 
    longList.stream()
            .map(Math::toIntExact) // throws ArithmeticException on under/overflow
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you would prefer to "saturate" the value you can do

```
Iterable<Integer> result = 
    longList.stream()
            .map(i -> (int) Math.min(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 
                                     Math.max(Integer.MIN_VALUE, i)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```